# Laptop crashes all time

Tags: windows-10, laptop, crash, ubuntu-16.04, memtest86+

Ever since I got my laptop, it crashes all the time:

- The screen starts to become 'colourful' (small colourful squares instead of of the normal screen);
- The speakers start to buzz;
- I have no control over the mouse/keyboard.

Originally I had Windows 10. Then I set it up to dual boot with Ubuntu 16.04, because I thought the system was the problem, but both on Win10 and Ubuntu 16.04 have the problem.

Today I did ran Memtest86+ and it didn't detected anything.

At the mem-test the temperature of CPU was from 40 to 50 Celcius degrees. The fans are working well so I think everything is all-right in this aspect. The problem is the PC does not crash at some hard things - BF1, Fifa18 (all at max settings), but on some primitive things as Chrome (one card of YouTube), etc

When I bought a laptop he had 4GB of RAM, so I added next 8GB. They didn't working (system even not starting). It was non-sense for me, 'cause they got all parameters to work well at co-operation (DDR4, MHz etc).

So I removed original 4GB and now have only this 'newer' 8.

I thought that if memtest didn't show anything, the RAM is good.

What can the problem be?

Specificaton of laptop:
Lenovo Legion Y520
GPU: GTX 1050
CPU: i7 7700HQ 
RAM: 8GB (don't remember the brand)
System: dual boot - Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Do you have any means of checking the Lenovo's temperature?

Comment: Thanks! At the mem-test the temperature of CPU was from 40 to 50 Celcius degrees. The fans are working well so I think everything is all-right in this aspect. The problem is the PC does not crash at some hard things - BF1, Fifa18 (all at max settings), but on some primitive things as Chrome (one card of YouTube), etc

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to have guessed, it looks like a hardware problem. Try looking at hardware monitoring tools, like [openhardwaremonitor](https://openhardwaremonitor.org/), and [gsmartcontrol](https://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.io/home/). Also additional hardware stress tests besides memtest86+, like prime95, and various benchmark software to stress cpu, video, and hdd as well, while monitoring the health with the monitoring tools mentioned earlier.

Check for dust buildup inside the laptop, particularly on the fans and cooling fins. What are you putting the laptop on? how is the airflow through the laptop when it is on that? what are the temperatures like? Many people are surprised to learn that a lap is not the best surface to run a laptop on, or a bed, or a couch. **Just because the fans are turning does not mean your cooling is working properly**. They may not be moving enough air due to blockages in the flow path, or that air flow is effective on dust covered cooling fins.

If the laptop is under warranty, I would be talking to the people you purchased it from to have them troubleshoot and fix it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new tho this site and I don't know how to mark/cite you in my answer.

Comment: @PanMikuś If you are providing extra detail on your question, generally edit your original question to include that info. If you are unclear on what someone's answer is saying, put it in a comment of that answer. Have a look at https://superuser.com/tour